# What is the best way to work with images in an API

Tags: python, image, fastapi

I am making a rest API where users can get and post images with labels. The API will also have the ability to generate color pallets for the images. I am wondering what the best way to post images to the API is and what format the API should store the images in. I am considering using base64 encoded images but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can encode and decode the files(images) using base64.
Its secure and relaiable.
OR
If you meant read/write by handle of images then best way to do so is by storing images into file system and then access them URL stored in a DB. If you want to process image by editing and then used cloud services to store in file systems like AWS S3, then you can focus on the editing part with Java/JavaScript plugins for browsers. But whether you edit or write to some DB it is always better to use file system to store image file physically and locate them using some URL from DB. REST or any APIs should be written keeping in mind the basic structure of file handling. Any file of large size should not be saved into DB as CLOB or BLOB even though nobody restricts you. It is better to save files(images) into file system like S3. I’ve written APIs for writing and reading files into DB which is small in size and need to be accessed very rarely.